# Find the maximum value of $\int^{3π/2}_{−π/2} \sin(x)f(x) dx$ subject to the constraint $|f(x)| ≤ 5$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the maximum value of $$\int^{3π/2}_{−π/2} \sin(x)f(x) dx$$ subject to the constraint $$|f(x)| ≤ 5$$

Choosing $f(x)$ to be piece-wise such that $f(x)=-5$ if $\sin{x}<0$ and $f(x)=5$ if $\sin x \geq0$, we get an upper bound of $20$. However, can we really claim such a function is admissible? It is discontinuous over the integration bounds, so surely this integral may not be defined in this case?

Comment: Well, you can get arbitrarily close with continuous functions (for example a sigmoid that approximates a unit step function.

Comment: The function you defined as $f(x)$ is certainly admissible. In fact, the function you defined satisfies $\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)dx=0$

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @MatthewHolder I am not convinced we get integrate such a function like this as it is not continuous.

Comment: @Janes Functions which possess a finite number of jump discontinuities are Riemann itegrable. See this here: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090706084751AA5GjOZ&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmluZy5jb20v&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAADl6Cm1iN3RsnrCxGodV4WpDhZvUxrvJs3mlwPqKDI9EHfZPcsyyGpRPjB8gyM25lAVgPRkEA1tTy6UsguDBEKFpO--Cx7xvdEmmFZMBPUnC4__AzjZ4gwySNOuTHj7fXEyKaAsocNbuKtC2AcoycMiDOYN1CwkZ57PG4m8InDyQ

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \sin x f(x) dx \le \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} |\sin x f(x)| dx  =\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} |\sin x| |f(x)|  dx $$ $$ \le 5 \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} |\sin x| dx \implies I \le 20 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x ~ dx =20.$$

Comment: This does not prove that it's a maximum, only an upper bound

Comment: Together with the function provided by the OP it proves this is a maximum.